# app crashes reported due to missing NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription, but my app never uses any photos

Tags: ios, crash, privacy

I'm seeing a few crash reports that say

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
```

> Termination Reason: TCC, This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

All very interesting, especially because *my app never goes anywhere near the photo library for any reason whatever*. So what on earth is going on here, and what's TCC anyhow?

I'm perfectly willing to add this key, but I have no explanation for why it would be needed so I can't supply any meaningful text!

Problem arises in iOS 12.1 only, though that might not be meaningful data as you can't prove a negative. I suspect an iOS bug of course, and will report this, but I'm curious as to whether anyone else has seen this odd phenomenon.

Here's a bit more of a typical crash report:

> Triggered by Thread:  3

[skipping thread 0 and 1]

```
Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019ffe3f0c semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019fe32f8c _dispatch_sema4_wait$VARIANT$mp + 24 (lock.c:134)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019fe33a10 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 136 (semaphore.c:132)
3   AssetsLibraryServices           0x00000001ade2d140 __79-[PLPrivacy _isPhotosAccessAllowedWithScope:forceHandler:accessAllowedHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 412 (PLPrivacy.m:183)
4   AssetsLibraryServices           0x00000001ade138b4 __pl_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 36 (PLDispatchHelpers.m:23)
[skipping the rest]

Thread 3 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019ffeddf8 __abort_with_payload + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019ffe7838 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 100 (terminate_with_reason.c:71)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019ffe7868 abort_with_payload + 12 (terminate_with_reason.c:93)
3   TCC                             0x00000001a32aea70 __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 204 (TCC.c:372)
4   TCC                             0x00000001a32ae9a4 __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke.77 + 708 (TCC.c:508)
5   TCC                             0x00000001a32b2a90 __tccd_send_message_block_invoke + 276 (TCC.c:220)
[skipping the rest]
```

Comment: It seems that something was trying to add a photo to the photo library.  Are there any other clues in the stack trace as to where it was in your code when the crash happened?

Comment: @Paulw11 I don't think there are, but I believe I've found the use case where this can happen. The odd thing is that it isn't _me_ (the app) that's doing the adding, it's the user, effectively acting out-of-process; this permission should not be needed. I regard this as a bug in iOS.

Comment: I was wondering if it was something like that; some way that the user is sharing an image or something into their photo library, which as you say, shouldn't be a privacy issue for your app to deal with

Comment: Same happens when use UIActivity View Controller and user press save to photo library !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the crash! Here's the deal: my app contains a web view. If the user presses on an image in that web view, a Save menu item appears. If the user taps Save, we need permission; if there's no privacy string in the *Info.plist*, we crash at that moment (and if there is one, we get the authorization dialog).

In my opinion, this is an iOS bug. I never intended for the user to do this; it's just a feature of web views. The act of saving from the web view to the photos library is therefore effectively out of process; it's the *user* who is doing it, not my app. And the user should not need permission; it's the user who tapped on the image and who then tapped the Save button. There is no way this scenario could have happened without the user making multiple deliberate moves, none of which involve my app directly. I'll be reporting this to Apple.

Comment: Can you please provide the URL of your filed bug report on this?

Comment: @NovaJoe It is radar # 46224031. But that won't do you any good; you can't see inside Apple's bugbase.

Comment: Can't believe how much time I've spent on this... And I was certain all my permissions were covered, but I would never have thought of this.

Comment: Just a note that this problem still exists, and still drives people (like me) crazy. It all has to do with permissions within a webview. We should not be responsible for these permissions. I don't want my users to feel like our app is doing more than it is. Apple needs to fix this.

Comment: So nobody else tries this - I added capture="filesystem" to the input field and it still causes the app to crash.