# How to disable Take Video when selecting a photo?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, webview, ios-camera

In the webview of my Xamarin application I have a html file input. When clicking on it I get 3 options on my iPhone:

1. Take Photo or Video
2. Photo Library
3. Search

Because there is a Video option in 1), I have to add NSCameraUsageDescription and NSMicrophoneUsageDescription to the info.plist and add the description why I need them. Since I do not need them I would like to disable the "take video" Option in the menu.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don’t think so. In my view, you should not need user permission because the user is explicitly choosing to take the photo or video. But because of this, you are forced to include these unnecessary permissions strings. Just include them and move on.

Comment: I added them and added a short description text why I need these permissions and my app was rejected in review because I need to write a better explanations. So I have to invent a reason out of thin air. That is why i want to avoid that.

Comment: I agree. This is similar to my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53439457/app-crashes-reported-due-to-missing-nsphotolibraryaddusagedescription-but-my-ap. I filed a bug with Apple on this. You should not need to supply a reason for an action that the user initiated outside your control. However, that's the way it is and the only option that you have is to make up a meaningful permission string.